# React-Native: How can I program a scroll that allows elements in a menu reappear once it has made its way around?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, swiper.js, mobile-development

I'm researching on how to make a swiping menu dial. [Like This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/icqlj4n0xsf4c71/Screen%20Shot%202017-10-03%20at%209.34.09%20AM.png?dl=0)

Since it is a mobile app, my idea is to allow the user to swipe their finger around the dial to move and see all the button options on the menu. I was thinking of using some sort of scrolling touch feature that could let the user keep swiping left or right till they see the same button options as it makes its way back completely around the dial. Anyone have an idea to recreate this menu dial?

Thanks in advance!!
- Jemma

Comment: That looks like it's going to be really tough to implement from scratch. I would try checking out the various resources that come up when Googling e.g. `react native  round menu`, you may be able to adapt them to your needs. (Just as a heads-up, "How do I..." type requests [that essentially amount to library recommendations and such] often don't fare well on Stack Overflow, as they tend to be off topic.)

Comment: @Pekka Thank you so much for your advice! I didn't think it would be so tough to code from scratch but I guess I was wrong! I will check out some libraries :)